# Why does the Cook PVI of states not predict whether another state has (statewide) elected officials of the other party?

Tags: united-states, election

I've noticed something interesting: that the partisanship of a state does not seem to predict the willingness of a state to vote for people from the other party.

Let's use January 1st, 2010 as a starting point for this (because people became more partisan a lot more following the Tea Party wave, but it only really started taking off afterwards), and look at a state's margin for Biden and Trump, and look towards the bottom and top of states that voted that way in 2016 and 2020. We will count the number of times the state elected a member of the other party statewide to one office, federal or not. This also includes presidential elections. (If the person switched parties in office, it counts halfway.) Examples:

1. Minnesota and Massachusetts. Minnesota is seen as a Democratic-leaning swing state (D+1), while Massachusetts is considered a solid blue state (D+14). Minnesota's score is zero, while Massachusetts has I believe a score of three, with Scott Brown and Charlie Baker. (Vermont's score is even higher, and MA has the usual caveat of local issues.)
2. Florida and West Virginia. Florida technically has a score of one, but that is a trivial case in a blue wave year, which was less than 1 tenth of a percent of the vote. Florida seems stronger for the GOP than in the past (R+3) but is seen as winnable on the presidential level for both parties. West Virginia was R+23. West Virginia has a score of at least 2 and a half, while Florida's is only barely one.

I'm not saying that the margin doesn't matter at all, but what I am saying is that it doesn't seem predictive of this metric of solidness of a state. You should note *strength* of partisanship. There is no state today that would be Democratic leaning and have all or even most Republicans statewide, or vice versa.

Maybe strength is the wrong word. The better term is "vote share" or "statewide performance" or "Cook PVI" or something like that. *Why do states that have lower partisan lean strength according to presidential results such as Minnesota or Florida sometimes at least historically seem less open to voting for the other party's candidate than states with higher partisan leans like Massachusetts and West Virginia?* (In a shorter sentence, why do some less "safe" states back one party more consistently at all statewide levels than more "safe" states?

By this metric, which uses a golf-like analysis (lower number supposedly means safer), Minnesota is arguably a safer blue state than Massachusetts.

Comment: What are you asking here? I am not sure what I am supposed to get from the examples you gave.

Comment: I am asking, *Why do states that have lower partisan lean strength according to presidential results such as Minnesota or Florida sometimes at least historically seem less open to voting for the other party's candidate than states with higher partisan leans like Massachusetts and West Virginia*?

Comment: In other words, I am asking **does the + number on the partisan leans effect elections that much**?

Comment: What examples do you have of this happening? I see the talk about it but nothing saying that X state leans towards Y party but elected a candidate from Z party. Just because something seems winnable doesn't mean a lot considering the history of some states.

Comment: Minnesota has not *elected* a Republican statewide official (governor, etc.) since before the starting date. But Massachusetts has elected them 3 times (Scott Brown 2010 for Senate and Charlie Baker 2014&2018 for governor). It doesn't say specifically, but it should make sense now? I tried to give you examples. Florida hasn't (in the same tone as Minnesota) had any Dem statewide officials other than a secretary of agriculture, who barely won. There are other examples, these are the most extreme examples I could find.

Comment: The obvious answer is that the candidates and the issues still matter, at least a little. It's still possible for Republicans to vote for a Democrat they trust, and it's still possible for Republicans to moderate

Comment: But look at the examples. Some light blue states don't vote that way in practice but other deep blue states do. You do have a point so I will upvote it. I am focusing on *why it happens in some deep blue/red states like MA+WV, but not in light blue/red states like FL+MN, or possibly even NV if you start in 2016. The core question is *why do some states seem more open than others?*

Comment: How confident are you that your statistical tools should reliably show an effect on this small number of samples? Have you tried to model this theoretically somehow, or is the expected correllation just gut feeling?

Comment: Because local politics and parties don't necessarily neatly line up with national politics.  Just look at southern Democrats up until very recently.

Comment: That is a good argument. It could explain a good deal of it.

Comment: @divibisan it could be evidence of the exact opposite too. If you actually care about *national* issues you vote for a party, not person, because that's how politics in extremely polarized environments work, at least currently.  The most recent votes are stark evidence towards this point, it's not like Susan Collins crossed over for covid relief.  Again, local politics can look very different which is why there's more crossover and weird looking outcomes there.

Comment: Those examples should be in the question not the comments

Comment: A concise way of looking at it would be to say national politics is now essentially fully **sorted** by ideology whereas local politics can still look like national politics did from the 50s until the 90s

Comment: The biggest point is that local politics is an issue issue that affects voting more often in certain states. I want to know more about different factors behind that.

Comment: I am not trying to make a point on anything or a biased question. I am just saying that there are different outliers. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook_Partisan_Voting_Index. In addition, I gave a fairly long time period (2010+) so that it can be fairly clear that some states seem more open than others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Because it's not designed for this purpose.**

Different politicians have different personalities.  To take two GOP Governors at random, there are some people who would vote for Spencer Cox (R-UT) but not Tate Reeves (R-MS), and others who are the reverse.  Therefore, you cannot compare partisanship off the back of a Gubernatorial vote because the candidates themselves are different.

The PVI looks at the Presidential ballot because it is the same GOP candidate and the same Democratic candidate in all 50 states, and so there is no need to consider a difference in personalities when making a comparison.

Comment: That is probably the best answer I could find. Thank you.

Comment: I would add to this that state-to-state, the party institutions and constituencies are different - which makes any attempt to compare them a fraught enterprise out the gate. The example I like to use is Joe Manchin: He's a Democrat in West Virginia, but in California he'd easily secure a nomination as a Republican. "D+#" doesn't mean much in that context.  PVI is, essentially, a measure of the national committees' relative strength at the regional (state) level.  I suspect you might see more predictive value if you looked at Senate/House races from those states, since there's dependence there.

Comment: I understand that. I was asking for more details on this, because this difference happens in some states but not others.